# Trazer resultados de um campo radio (array)

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema do qual traz do banco de dados a relação dos usuários da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para isso, o código está assim:

```
public function listarUsuarios($id,$usuarios){

.....
 $listar .= "<div style='display=block'><table class='table table-bordered'>
                     <thead>
                      <tr>
                       <th style='background-color: #4682B4; color: #FFF; text-align: center'>USUÁRIO</th>
                       <th style='background-color: #4682B4; color: #FFF; text-align: center'>COMPARECEU</th>
                        <th style='background-color: #4682B4; color: #FFF; text-align: center'>JUSTIFICATIVA</th>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>";
      while($jmListar = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlListar)){
             $listar .= "<tr>";
             $listar .= "<td>
             <input type='hidden' name='Usuarios[]' value='".$jmListar->IdCadastros."'>
             <i class=\"fa fa-caret-right\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> ".$jmListar->NomeUsuarios."
             </td>
             <td>
          <div class='radio-group'>
              <label class='radio-label'>
                  <input name='Presenca[".$jmListar->IdCadastros."]' type='radio' checked='checked' value='S' onclick=\"desabilitar('N')\">
                  <span class='inner-label' style='color: #008000; font-weight: bold'>Sim</span>
              </label>
              <label class='radio-label'>
                  <input name='Presenca[".$jmListar->IdCadastros."]' type='radio' value='N' onclick=\"desabilitar('S')\">
                  <span class='inner-label' style='color: #F00; font-weight: bold'>Não</span>
              </label>
           </div>
         </td>";
        $listar .= "<td><textarea name='Justificado[]' class='form-control' id='justificativa' disabled></textarea></td>";
        $listar .= "</tr>";      
      }
      $listar .= "</table></form>";
      return $listar;
}
```

Mas ao cadastrar, ele está me retornando dessa forma:

```
INSERT INTO pe_presenca VALUES(null,'1','N','teste Justificativa', NOW());
INSERT INTO pe_presenca VALUES(null,'57','S','', NOW());
```

Na segunda coluna é armazenado o ID do usuário, sendo que o **ID 1** é o Fernando Pessoa e o **ID 57** é o Carlos Chagas.

O que está ocorrendo é que ele está cadastrando de forma errada, já que o Carlos Chagas (ID 57) recebeu o valor **Não** e a **justificativa**, e não o Fernando Pessoa (ID 1). O código está dessa forma:

```
if($_POST){
   $usuarios = $_POST["Usuarios"];
   $presenca = $_POST["Presenca"];
   $justificativa = $_POST["Justificativa"];
   echo $metodos->cadastrarPresenca($usuarios,$presenca,$justificar);
}
```

E o método que estou cadastrando:

```
public function cadastrarPresenca($usuarios,$presenca,$justificar){
....
      list($dia,$mes,$ano) = explode("/",$dataPresenca);
        $dataPresenca = $ano."-".$mes."-".$dia;

        for($i = 0; $i <= count($usuarios); $i++){
            $presenca[$i] = ($presenca[$i] == "S")?'S':'N';
            echo "INSERT INTO pe_presenca VALUES(null,'".$usuarios[$i]."','".$presenca[$i]."','".$justificar[$i]."', NOW());";
    }
exit;
.....
}
```

Gostaria que o cadastro fosse feito na ordem correta. Alguém sabe me informar onde está o erro? Acredito que seja no modo como estou pegando o valor da presença `Presenca[".$jmListar->IdCadastros."]`, mas não vejo outro meio de pegar o valor sem ser dessa forma.

Comment: Seria melhor por índice em todos os nomes, pra ficar igual: `Usuarios[".$jmListar->IdCadastros."]'`, mesma coisa pro Justificado. Depois você usa um foreach ,,, as $id => $usuário no lugar do for, e pega os ítens correspondentes com [$id] dentro do loop

Comment: Perfeito Bacco. Funcionou! Obrigado!

Comment: Se puder, poste como resposta o código funcional, ai já fecha a questão

Comment: Certo. Coloquei como resposta ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resultado final:

Alterei os campos para `Usuarios[".$jmListar->IdCadastros."]` e `Justificado[".$jmListar->IdCadastros."]` e cadastrei da seguinte forma:

```
public function cadastrarPresenca($usuarios,$presenca,$justificar){
....
      list($dia,$mes,$ano) = explode("/",$dataPresenca);
        $dataPresenca = $ano."-".$mes."-".$dia;

    foreach($usuarios as $id => $usuario){
            $presenca[$id] = ($presenca[$id] == "S")?'S':'N';
            mysqli_query($this->conexao,"INSERT INTO pe_presenca VALUES(null,'".$usuarios[$id]."','".$presenca[$id]."','".$justificar[$id]."', NOW());");
    }

.....
}
```